# using history with react-router dom on v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I use `react-router-dom` version 6 and when I use `onClick={history.push("/movies")` this is not working

**Movie Form.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
const MovieForm = ({ history }) => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>{id}</h1>
      <button
        className="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
        onClick={history.push("/movies")}
      >
        Save
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MovieForm;
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'push')

Comment: In v6 you can call `useNavigate`: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-navigate

Comment: history object is not getting passed it seems

Comment: Can you explain ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `react-router-dom@6` there are no longer any route props, i.e. no `location`, `history`, and `match` props. Use the `useNavigate` hook, which replaced the RRDv5 `useHistory` hook, to access the `navigate` function and issue the imperative navigation. Make sure that you also don't immediately invoke the `button` element's `onClick` handler, pass it an anonymous callback that calls `navigate`.

Example:

```
import React from "react";
import { useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const MovieForm = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>{id}</h1>
      <button
        className="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
        onClick={() => navigate("/movies")}
      >
        Save
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: is there any way to run some script before leaving the page with react router v6 ?

Comment: @Gurupalsingh Sure. React class components have the `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle method and React function components have the returned cleanup function of the `useEffect` hook. These handle when the component unmounts gracefully. For the times the page is forcefully reloaded or similar there's the [beforeunload event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event) that a component can setup listeners for.

Comment: this will work on route change too ?

Comment: @Gurupalsingh Sure, if the route change causes the component to unmount because the app is navigating to another page.